# PHPExcel and domPDF not generating the file

Tags: php, export, phpexcel, dompdf

I am trying to generate an excel file using PHPExcel and convert it to PDF using domPDF. The error is 500

Here's my code so far.

```
    function createPDF($filename){



   //PHPExcel
   require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/plugin/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

   $inputFile = dirname(__FILE__) . '/export/'.$filename.'.xls';
   $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFile);
   $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
   $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFile);
   $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

   $rendererName = PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_DOMPDF;
   $rendererLibrary = 'dompdf';
   $rendererLibraryPath = dirname(__FILE__) . '/plugin/dompdf/'.$rendererLibrary;
   $rendererLibraryPath .= '.php';

   var_dump($rendererLibraryPath);

   if (!PHPExcel_Settings::setPdfRenderer($rendererLibrary,$rendererLibraryPath)){
    die(
        'NOTICE: Please set the $rendererName and $rendererLibraryPath values' .
        '<br />' .
        'at the top of this script as appropriate for your directory structure'
       );
   }

   header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.pdf"');
   header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
   $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'PDF');
   ob_end_clean();
   $objWriter->save(str_replace('summaryOnLateReportSubmissions.php', 'export/' . $filename . '.pdf', __FILE__));
   return true;
}
```

I can't seem to figure out the problem for more than a day now. TIA

Comment: `$rendererLibraryPath` should be the path to the installed DomPDF, not to PHPExcel's wrapper..... PHPExcel knows where its wrapper is, it doesn't know where you've installed DompDF

Comment: Hi, where should I put the dompdf folder? that seems to be the problem.

Comment: You install DomPDF wherever you want on your system; then you set `$rendererLibraryPath` to tell PHPExcel where you've installed it

Comment: There seem to be a problem with the renderer setting. Coz when I ran, it shows the 'NOTICE: Please set the $renderName....'

Comment: This is the directory where I put the dompdf files: /api/plugin/dompdf/dompdf.php